# Dynamic Programming approach issue

Tags: python, combinations, dynamic-programming, permutation

Alice goes for jogging every day for N meters. Sometimes she runs and sometimes she walks. Her walking speed is 1m/s and running speed is 2m/s . Given the distance up to which she does jogging, calculate the number of ways she can do jogging.

example:

Input: 3 (total distance covered during jogging)

Output: 3 (possible case)

Explanation:
Alice could jog in 3 ways

1. Alice Walks for 3 meter
2. Alice Run for 2 meters and then walks for 1 m
3. Alice walks 1m and then run 2m

Example 2:

Input: 4

Output: 5

Explanation: Alice could jog in 5 ways

1. Alice walk for all 4 meters
2. Alice walk for first 2 meters and then run for 2 meters
3. Alice could run for 2 meters and then walk for 2 meters
4. Alice walk for 1 meters and then run  for 2 meters and then walk for 1 meters
5. Alice run for all 4 meters

I have solved above problem statement using following code

```py
from itertools import permutations

n = int(input())

c = 0
t = [2]*(n//2)
if n % 2 != 0:
    t = t+[1]

for i in range(t.count(2)):
    c = c+len(set(list(permutations(t, len(t)))))
    t.remove(2)
    t.append(1)
    t.append(1)
c = c+len(set(list(permutations(t, len(t)))))
print(c)
```

I'm new in dynamic programming, any one can help me ? how i can implement this in dynamic approach method and achieve more optimum time complexivity?

Thankyou very much for giving your valuable towards my problem.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement. Alice must choose a number `a` of meters to walk and a number `b` of meters to run, such that `a+b=N`? There are only `N+1` possibilities. No need for any kind of algorithm here, just return `N+1`.

Comment: I don't understand the example you give. Why is the output `3` and not `4` in this case? You ignore the solution where Alice runs for 3 meters?

Comment: *"Her walking speed is 1m/s and running speed is 2m/s ."* Is this information relevant at all to the problem? How?

Comment: @Stef Alice either can walk at 1m/s or run at 2m/s. Given the information that she covered distance of total 2m, it is not possible that she covers total distance by only running. if she tries to cover the distance by running it will be multiples of 2 that's why it's not possible

Comment: How do you know that she "covered distance of total 2m"? I don't see that anywhere in the problem statement.

Comment: @Stef So sorry for the typo mistake, it's 4 which is given as an input

Comment: It seems like the question is the same as "how many ways to go up N steps taking 1 or 2 steps at a time" to which the answer is fib(N+1)

Comment: The missing part of the question seems to be the unwritten assumption that Alice can change between walking and running only at integer second boundaries.

Comment: @PaulHankin yes you are correct.

Comment: @PaulHankin has indicated the answer earlier, under the disguise, it's fib seq.  If all unwritten assumptions are true..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by all earlier posts, and the unwritten assumptions being confirmed, this is just another **fib-sequence** question.

Credits to all earlier posters.  (*the code is quite simple then)* Just for reference - hope it helps.

```
def jogging_ways(n: int) -> int:
    # f(3) = f(1) + f(2)
    a, b = 1, 1
        
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a+b
        #print(a, b)
        
    return a
```

Running:

```
> jogging_ways(4)
  5
> jogging_ways(5) 
  8
```